# What gallery script is this?

Tags: javascript, flash

I really need to know what flash photo gallery is used on this site? 
http://www.shad0w.ru/impression.html

Also do you know any similar javascript script?

Comment: Not sure why this question was voted down. Giving it an up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the gallery is:
http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/

there are plenty of JavaScript photo galleries available -
one i like is http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/demo_01.htm

hope that helps.